# git rebase vs git cherry-pick of detached branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have two branches:

1. master
2. tmp

`tmp` branch is detached
I need to put `tmp` branch on top of `master` with resolving conflicts in priority of `tmp`

When I do

```
git checkout tmp
git rebase --strategy=recursive -X theirs master
```

I got error
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...

```
fatal: Could not parse object '0a722ac51071ecb4d00b1ef45384aac227b942a0^'  
Unknown exit code (128) from command: git-merge-recursive 0a722ac51071ecb4d00b1ef45384aac227b942a0^ -- HEAD 0a722ac51071ecb4d00b1ef45384aac227b942a0
```

When I do

```
git checkout tmp
git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs 0a722ac..384144a
```

Works fine

What the difference or how can I do the same with rebase ?

Answer (score 7):

You're getting the `rebase` error because you didn't explicitly tell it which commit to start with, and because you did explicitly tell it to invoke merge, it went looking for the merge base<sup>1</sup>.  To tell it not to bother, to just take the whole branch, specify `--root`:

```
git checkout tmp
git rebase --strategy=recursive -X theirs --root master
```

Your `cherry-pick` didn't do what you think it did.  The `..` construct means "not the commit on the left or anything reachable from it ...", in particular, in this case, it means "not 0a722ac".  It didn't cherry-pick the whole branch.  Since cherry-pick is built to expect single commits, you do have to explicitly specify a range, the way to do it here is to simply default the exclusion set to `HEAD` (since `HEAD` has nothing in common with `tmp`, nothing will be excluded):

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs  ..tmp
```

The asymmetry in the range specification is just a consequence of the two commands' most common usage: rebase applies to the whole of the current branch, while cherry-pick is generally used for one or more single commits..

---

<sup>1</sup> not very intelligently, but rebasing branches with their own complicated merge history wholesale (linear whole-branch rebase works fine) is going to itch so very few people I doubt you'll be able to drum up much desire to help scratch it.

Answer (score 2):

A [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is done by moving all commits *after* a certain commit: here after the parent of `0a722ac`.

A [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) take a list of commits and replicate them: 0a722ac..384144a

Since `0a722ac^` isn't accessible (that is the case, for instance, for an orphan branch, where 0a722ac would be the very first commit), rebase will fail, cherry-pick (which doesn't need to access to the parent of 0a722ac) will succeed.

See more at "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309)".